# OpenGL: Compute eye space coord from window space coord in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

How do I compute an eye space coordinate from window space (pixel in the frame buffer) coordinates + pixel depth value in GLSL please (gluUnproject in GLSL so to speak)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a guy on opengl.org has pointed out that the clip space coordinates the projection produces are divided by clipPos.w to compute the normalized device coordinates. When reversing the steps from fragment over ndc to clip space coordinates, you need to reconstruct that w (which happens to be -z from the corresponding view space (camera) coordinate), and multiply the ndc coordinate with that value to compute the proper clip space coordinate (which you can turn into a view space coordinate by multiplying it with the inverse projection matrix).

The following code assumes that you are processing the frame buffer in a post process. When processing it while rendering geometry, you can use gl_FragCoord.z instead of texture2D (sceneDepth, ndcPos.xy).r.

Here is the code:

```
uniform sampler2D sceneDepth;
uniform mat4 projectionInverse;
uniform vec2 clipPlanes; // zNear, zFar
uniform vec2 windowSize; // window width, height

#define ZNEAR clipPlanes.x
#define ZFAR clipPlanes.y

#define A (ZNEAR + ZFAR)
#define B (ZNEAR - ZFAR)
#define C (2.0 * ZNEAR * ZFAR)
#define D (ndcPos.z * B)
#define ZEYE -(C / (A + D))

void main() 
{
vec3 ndcPos;
ndcPos.xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / windowSize;
ndcPos.z = texture2D (sceneDepth, ndcPos.xy).r; // or gl_FragCoord.z
ndcPos -= 0.5;
ndcPos *= 2.0;
vec4 clipPos;
clipPos.w = -ZEYE;
clipPos.xyz = ndcPos * clipPos.w;
vec4 eyePos = projectionInverse * clipPos;
}
```

Basically this is a GLSL version of gluUnproject.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be duplicate of [GLSL convert gl_FragCoord.z into eye-space z](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4918599/607131).

Edit (complete answer):

```
// input: x_coord, y_coord, samplerDepth
vec2 xy = vec2(x_coord,y_coord); //in [0,1] range
vec4 v_screen = vec4(xy, texture(samplerDepth,xy), 1.0 );
vec4 v_homo = inverse(gl_ProjectionMatrix) * 2.0*(v_screen-vec4(0.5));
vec3 v_eye = v_homo.xyz / v_homo.w; //transfer from homogeneous coordinates
```

Comment: I have read your reply to that question. First of all I do not just want to reconstruct z. And then your reply contains seemingly completely unrelated stuff, i.e. you are using some variables in one code line that never get referenced in the following ones. When I read that I asked myself what you had been smoking when posting that reply. (j/k) ;-)

Comment: @karx11erx: the answer was not as bad as you are saying, but I've put a fixed version here for your reference.

Comment: Ah cool. Thanks. I think it's still not quite right. You grab v_screen from the depth buffer, and in the next line you are using read_depth. I reckon they're identical. Problem is though, I don't have the original projection matrix. What I am trying to do is to apply shadow maps in a post process after the entire frame has been rendered. So I am having an FBO with color and depth buffers, and the shadow map. It doesn't quite work though. See here for details: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=295642#Post295642

Comment: Ah, I see you edited your code here. I was referring to the other question you had linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've stuck with a fixed pipeline-style model, view and projection, you can just implement exactly the formula given in the [gluUnProject man page](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluUnProject.3G.html).

There's no matrix inversion built into GLSL, so ideally you'd so that on the CPU. So you need to supply a uniform of the inverse of your composed modelViewProjection matrix. gl_FragCoord is in window coordinates, so you also need to supply the view dimensions.

So, you'd probably end up with something like (coding extemporaneously):

```
vec4 unProjectedPosition = invertedModelViewProjection * vec4( 
               2.0 * (gl_FragCoord.x - view[0]) / view[2] - 1.0, 
               2.0 * (gl_FragCoord.y - view[1]) / view[3] - 1.0,
               2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - 1.0,
               1.0);
```

If you've implemented your own analogue of the old matrix stack then you're probably fine inverting a matrix. Otherwise, it's possibly a [more daunting topic](http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q24) than you had anticipated and you might be better off using MESA's [open source implementation](http://webcvs.freedesktop.org/mesa/Mesa/src/glu/mesa/project.c?view=markup) (see invert_matrix, the third function in that file), just because it's well tested if nothing else.

Comment: It's the same values returned by a glGetIntegerv for GL_VIEWPORT. You should also mentally modify my answer as per kvark's below: invert turns up in a more recent version of the GLSL spec than I seem to be familiar with. You wouldn't want to do it per fragment though, probably, as it'll be very expensive.

Comment: Thanks. So view [0 .. 3] = left, right, bottom, top? I am having a matrix inversion function, no problem. Actually I am using that already (see my reply to kvark's comment for details).

Comment: Yep, that sounds right — so you're turning x and y into numbers in the range [-1, 1] to cover the entire axes. I was literally transcribing the contents of the man page linked, so that gives full details, apologies for leaving the meaning of 'view' a little vague in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that it's unnecessary to do these computations in the fragment shader. You can save a couple operations by doing this on the CPU and multiplying it with the MVP inverse (assuming `glDepthRange(0, 1)`, feel free to edit):

```
glm::vec4 vp(left, right, width, height);
glm::mat4 viewportMat = glm::translate(
    vec3(-2.0 * vp.x / vp.z - 1.0, -2.0 * vp.y / vp.w - 1.0, -1.0))
  * glm::scale(glm::vec3(2.0 / vp.z, 2.0 / vp.w, 2.0));
glm::mat4 mvpInv = inverse(mvp);
glm::mat4 vmvpInv = mvpInv * viewportMat;
shader->uniform("vmvpInv", vmvpInv);
```

In the shader:

```
vec4 eyePos = vmvpInv * vec4(gl_FragCoord.xyz, 1);
vec3 pos = eyePos.xyz / eyePos.w;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all available answers are touching the problem from an aspect, and `khronos.org` has a Wiki page with a few different cases listed and explained with shader code, so it's worth posting here.
[Compute eye space from window space](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space).